Github release generating multiple action workflows instead of one
we have a GitHub action which is below, setup to run the deployment step for a release. However whenever we create a release it creates 3 GitHub actions jobs rather than one. I'm not clear if it's a GitHub bug or incorrect logic in the GitHub action (most likely)
name: Trigger auto deployment

# When this action will be executed
on:
  # Automatically trigger it when detected changes in repo
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  # Allow manual trigger
  workflow_dispatch:
  pull_request:
    types: ["opened", "edited", "reopened", "synchronize", "ready_for_review"]

jobs:
  fail_if_pull_request_is_draft:
    if: github.event.pull_request.draft == true
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Fails in order to indicate that pull request needs to be marked as ready to review
        run: exit 1

  ci:
    name:  Build, lint, test
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    if: github.event.pull_request.draft == false
    timeout-minutes: 30
    services:
      edgedb:
        image: edgedb/edgedb:4
        env:
          EDGEDB_SERVER_SECURITY: insecure_dev_mode
        ports:
          - 5656:5656
    steps:
      - name: ⬇️ Checkout repo
        uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: ⎔ Setup node
        uses: actions/setup-node@v4
        with:
          cache: npm
          cache-dependency-path: ./package-lock.json
          node-version: 18

      - name:  Install deps
        run: npm ci

      # We can lint before installing EdgeDB, so do that first to fail fast
      - name:  Lint
        run: npm run lint

      - name:  Install EdgeDB
        uses: edgedb/setup-edgedb@v1
        with:
          server-dsn: edgedb://localhost:5656
          instance-name: ci_edgedb_instance

      - name: Test edgedb query
        run: edgedb query "SELECT 'Hello from GitHub Actions'"

      # Don't need migration as setup above does it
      - name:  Generate EdgeQL client
        run: npm run db:migrate

      - name:  Type check
        run: npm run typecheck

      - name:  Copy test env vars
        run: cp .env.example .en

      - name:  Seed the database
        run: npm run seed

      - name: ️ Build the server
        run: npm run build

      - name:  Cypress run
        uses: cypress-io/github-action@v6

        with:
          start: npm run start
          wait-on: "http://localhost:5173"
          record: true
        env:
          PORT: "5173"
          # pass GitHub token to detect new build vs re-run build
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN}}
          # overwrite commit message sent to Cypress Cloud
          COMMIT_INFO_MESSAGE: ${{github.event.pull_request.title}}
          # re-enable PR comment bot
          COMMIT_INFO_SHA: ${{github.event.pull_request.head.sha}}
          # For recording and parallelization to work you must set your CYPRESS_RECORD_KEY
          # in GitHub repo → Settings → Secrets → Actions
          CYPRESS_RECORD_KEY: ${{ secrets.CYPRESS_RECORD_KEY }}

      - name: Archive screenshots
        if: failure()
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v4
        with:
          name: screenshots
          path: ./cypress/screenshots

      - name: Archive videos
        if: always()
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v4
        with:
          name: cypress-videos
          path: ./cypress/videos

  build-and-deploy:
    name: ️ build and deploy
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    if: startsWith( github.ref, 'refs/tags/')
    timeout-minutes: 30
    environment: AXPEnv
    permissions:
      id-token: write
      contents: read
    services:
      edgedb:
        image: edgedb/edgedb:4
        env:
          EDGEDB_SERVER_SECURITY: insecure_dev_mode
        ports:
          - 5656:5656
    steps:
      - name: ⬇️ Checkout repo
        uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: ⎔ Setup node
        uses: actions/setup-node@v4
        with:
          cache: npm
          cache-dependency-path: ./package-lock.json
          node-version: 18

      - name:  Install EdgeDB
        uses: edgedb/setup-edgedb@v1
        with:
          server-dsn: edgedb://localhost:5656
          instance-name: ci_edgedb_instance

      - name: ✈️ Azure Login
        uses: azure/login@v2
        with:
          client-id: ${{ secrets.AZURE_CLIENT_ID }}
          tenant-id: ${{ secrets.AZURE_TENANT_ID }}
          subscription-id: ${{ secrets.AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID }}

      - name:  Querybuilder
        run: npm run db:migrate

      - name: Build and push container image to registry
        uses: azure/container-apps-deploy-action@v2
        with:
          registryUrl: axpreg.azurecr.io
          registryUsername: ${{ secrets.REGISTRY_USERNAME }}
          registryPassword: ${{ secrets.REGISTRY_PASSWORD }}
          containerAppName: someapp
          resourceGroup: somegroup
          appSourcePath: ${{ github.workspace }}
          imageToBuild: axpreg.azurecr.io/someapp:${{ github.ref_name }}
          environmentVariables: "..."


Your workflow does not get triggered on a release. It does not have this trigger:
on:
  release:
    types: [created]

The workflow runs you see are most likely other workflows in this repo that get triggered by a release event. You can see a workflow name on the run in the UI. Release event does not show a branch for a run.
Note: I understood that the three jobs you are referring to are workflow runs that you see when you click on the Actions tab for this repo.
